# Setting checkbox as checked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, checkbox

I have two input checkboxes, and I want to check/uncheck them with jQuery:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user1" value="1" id="u1" onclick="loadUserCalendar(1)">
<input type="checkbox" name="user2" value="2" id="u2" onclick="loadUserCalendar(2)">
```

JavaScript code:

```
var list = new cookieList("calendar_users"); 
var users = list.items();
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    $('input[name="user' + users[i].substr(1,1) + '"]').attr('checked', true);
    console.log('substring: ' + users[i].substr(1,1));
    console.log('enabling user ' + users[i]);
}
```

`var users` contains these values: `u1,u2` . To only get the user ID, I perform a substring, which gets me the correct number as you can see below in the console output.

Console output:

```
substring: 1
enabling user u1
substring: 2 
enabling user u2
```

I have no idea, why the checkboxes are not checked when the code ran. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**: I am using jQuery 1.4.4 due to compatibility reasons, that's why I am using `.attr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline event handlers (`onclick="loadUserCalendar(1)"`) are not the jQuery way. You should not have any in your html. Get rid of them and add to your jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click',':checkbox', function() {
        loadUserCalendar($(this).val());
    });
});
```

But maybe what you wanted was this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click',':checkbox', function() {
        $('form :checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
```

The jquery 1.ancient version:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function() {
        // do things
    });
});
```

Comment: It says this: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? 1.4.potato?

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.4.4 due to compatibility reasons

Comment: You mean due to incompatibility reasons, lol. I've updated my answer. Please consider updating your compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for this. This fixed the "not jQuery way". If I reload my page, I lose the checked checkboxes again, and that was my main problem. Do you also have an answer for this?

Comment: When are you calling the function? If this js is in the <head> element, then you need to wait for jquery and the entire page to load before doing anything. Look at this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: That was exactly the problem. It was not inside the `$(document).ready(function () {` part. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?

You have to try something like :

```
$('input[name="user' + users[i].substr(1,1) + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or

```
$('input[name="user' + users[i].substr(1,1) + '"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

The second one is jQuery 1.6+

Comment: Hey, I tried the first approach but still no result. The checkbox is not being checked. The second one cannot be used as I am using jQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

When you want something to be checked you have to do the following:

```
 $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: Please make shure that you have the right selector $('!your selector!').attr('checked', 'checked);

Comment: This is exactly the question and that's why I posted this question. If you think the selector is wrong, please tell me the correct one and I will accept it as answer.

Comment: Maybe its a JQuery problem. I would suggest you not using such complex statements. Rather use the id selector with #u1, #u2, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the checkboxes dynamically use jQuery on method, because simple functions won't be able to access these elements.

Comment: live has been deprecated for centuries.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the initialization of the checkboxes I would suggest something like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, box) {
    $(box).attr('checked', $.inArray($(box).attr("id"), users) != -1);
});
```